# how to make row flash every 3 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms

I dont know if I'm doing this correctly but I have a grid and I loop through the grid to see if the items matched. If they do I want to make the row flash every 3 seconds. Right now what I have in my code just pretty much highlight the row but no flashing. Can anyone help take a look?

```
public static void CheckRow(int item, DataGridViewRow row)
{
    List<int> col = new List<int>();
    //call to db and add to col

    foreach (var item in col)
    {
        if (item == col.Item)
        {
            currentRow = row;
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.Interval = 3000;
            t.Tick += new System.EventHandler(Highlight);
            t.Start();
        }
    }
}

private static void Highlight(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Brown;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `CheckRow()`?

Comment: I can only see you changing the color to brown, and not back again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you need to change the color again (to the original) to have a flashing effect?

Comment: Agreed, but I'm thinking that there would have be some short delay before the "set back" otherwise, the change might happen so quickly, the human eye wouldn't be able to pick it up.

Comment: firstly, you look like you use "currentRow" as a way of getting in your Highlight method the row you want to change... is that what you really want?  what if more than one row needs to flash?  I would probably look at using background worker threads, invoke the ui thread to set the color on the desired row (passing the row as an argument to the background worker thread) and then sleep (on the background thread) and then re-invoke the row's color change back to the original color.  At least that seems like one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Threading. Look at the code :)

```
bool go = false; //for changing cell color
    int count = 10; //to stop timer (blinking)
    public blinkForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        Thread a = new Thread(blink);
        a.Start();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            //generate new columns for DataGridView
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("user", "User");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("pcStatus", "PC Status");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("service", "Servis");

            //generate new rows for DataGridView
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Ali", "PC007", "chrome.exe");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Vusal", "PC010", "photoshop.exe");
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Rahim", "PC015", "chrome.exe");
        }

    }

    private void blink(object o)
    {
        while (count > 0)
        {
            while (!go)
            {
                //change color for binking
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["service"].Style.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
                go = true;
                //stop for 0.5 second
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

            while (go)
            {
                //change color for binking
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["service"].Style.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                go = false;
                //stop for 0.5 second
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count--;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            //stop blinking after 10 second
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps this, no?

```
private static void Highlight(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Brown;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    currentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```